# A subquery in SQL Server returned more than 1 value

Tags: c#, sql-server

I made a Stored Procedure in SQL SERVER. When I call the stored procedure in the c# application, the following error occurs: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, , >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

I don't understand why this error occurs, because I am returning 1 single INT value.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spToevoegenUitslag]
    @intPersoonID INT,
    @intPersoonIDSnelsteRonde INT,
    @intPersoonIDPolePosition INT,
    @intGrandPrixID INT,
    @intPuntenID INT,
    @intSeizoenID INT,
    @intID INT = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    --Toevoegen punten van uitslag GrandPrix
    SELECT @intID = COUNT(ID) + 1 FROM tblPuntenCoureur

    INSERT INTO tblPuntenCoureur (ID, PersoonID, GrandPrixID, PuntenID, SeizoenID)
    VALUES (@intID, @intPersoonID, @intGrandPrixID, @intPuntenID, @intSeizoenID)

    --Toevoegen deelnemers van de GrandPrix
    SELECT @intID = COUNT(ID) + 1 FROM tblGrandPrixPersoon

    INSERT INTO tblGrandPrixPersoon (ID, GrandPrixID, PersoonID)
    VALUES (@intID, @intGrandPrixID, @intPersoonID)

    IF (SELECT ID FROM tblSnelsteRonde WHERE GrandPrixID = @intGrandPrixID AND SeizoenID = @intSeizoenID) IS NULL
        BEGIN
        SELECT @intID = COUNT(ID) + 1 FROM tblSnelsteRonde
        INSERT INTO tblSnelsteRonde (ID, PersoonID, intPunt, GrandPrixID, SeizoenID)
        VALUES (@intID, @intPersoonIDSnelsteRonde, 1, @intGrandPrixID, @intSeizoenID)
        END

    IF (SELECT ID FROM tblPolePosition WHERE GrandPrixID = @intGrandPrixID AND SeizoenID = @intSeizoenID) IS NULL
        BEGIN
        SELECT @intID = COUNT(ID) + 1 FROM tblPolePosition
        INSERT INTO tblPolePosition (ID, PersoonID, GrandPrixID, SeizoenID)
        VALUES (@intID, @intPersoonIDPolePosition, @intGrandPrixID, @intSeizoenID)
        END

    RETURN 1 --Toevoegen uitslag gelukt
END
```

c# code

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spToevoegenUitslag", verbinding))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@intPersoonID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PersoonID[0];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@intPersoonIDSnelsteRonde", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PersoonIDSnelsteRonde;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@intPersoonIDPolePosition", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PersoonIDPolePosition;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@intGrandPrixID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = GrandPrixID;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@intPuntenID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = PuntenID[0];
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@intSeizoenID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = SeizoenID;

                var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@Return", SqlDbType.Int);
                returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

                verbinding.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                var result = returnParameter.Value;

                int returnwaarde = int.Parse(string.Format("{0}", result));
                Console.WriteLine(returnwaarde);

                string title = "Resultaat";
                string message = "";

                if (returnwaarde == 1)
                {
                    message = "Uitslag succesvol toegevoegd";
                    MessageBox.Show(message, title);
                }
                verbinding.Close();
```

Comment: Please paste the c# code into the question and remove the image.

Comment: FYI, `RETURN` is normally used for denoting the success of a Stored Procedure and **`0`** denotes success, while anything else means failure (and normally the `RETURN` value is the error code). Returning `1` *implies* that your SP always fails.

Comment: Also, the `SELECT @intID = COUNT(ID) + 1` technique makes the code vulnerable to race condition bugs. You should be using `IDENTITY` columns or `SEQUENCE` values here instead.

Comment: As for the error, what about it don't you understand? This error is one of the clearer ones in SQL Server; your subquery is returning more than 1 row when it isn't allowed to.

Comment: The subqueries you use in the conditions for the `IF`s are problematic here. If they return more than one row they cannot be used in a `IS NULL` comparison. Maybe  you want to use `NOT EXISTS` instead or change the subqueries in a way that they only return a maximum of one row.

Answer (score 0):

`(SELECT ID FROM tblSnelsteRonde WHERE GrandPrixID = @intGrandPrixID AND SeizoenID = @intSeizoenID)` This query of yours might return more than one value if there is more than one row in the table with the given `@intGrandPrixID` and `@intSeizoenID`

You can try something Like `(SELECT Count(ID) FROM tblSnelsteRonde WHERE GrandPrixID = @intGrandPrixID AND SeizoenID = @intSeizoenID) == 0`. If this is what you intend to do

Comment: There is no `==` operator in T-SQL.